# Ways to reliably split a URL string and extract required part

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I am working on server side application of FB login.

Having converted the example here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

To VB, and using System.Net.WebRequest.Create to retrieve the responses I am now able to get a text string including the access_token and the expiry time in the following format:

```
   access_token=ACCESS&expires=2577
```

Obviously I can split this into an array and split the parts to get the `access_token`

But, on the FB Developers example above, they do it with PHP like so:

```
    $params['access_token'];
```

Is there a VB.net way of doing this? This seems more reliable to me than teh aforementioned splitting idea, ie, if FB change the output format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) to parse a query string. If you're not using ASP.NET, you should add a reference to `System.Web.dll`. I also don't believe this will work in .NET 4 client profile.

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Dim qString As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("var1=val1&var2=val2")
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.
`Dim queryString As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(tokenOutput)
            Return queryString("access_token")`